# Please help me with pascal to c# code conversion

Tags: c#, delphi, byte

Here is my **Pascal** code that I need converted

```pascal
function ByteToHex(InByte : Byte) : ShortString;
  const
    Digits : array[0..15] of char = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  begin
    result := Digits[InByte shr 4] + Digits[InByte and $0F];
  end;
```

I have *no experience* with **Delphi** but I'm working on converting a class to **C#** for my use and I'm stuck on this...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? FWIW, Stack Overflow is not a code conversion site.

Comment: Reinventing wheel, huh? [The Hexadecimal ("X") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#XFormatString)

Comment: Instead of attempting to convert from one language to another, you should probably describe what it is you want your c# function to do - what parameters it can take in and what output should it provide. Peter Wolf's link can help, so can this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Byte_ToString_System_String_

Comment: From my experience with Delphi: Throw it away and code from scratch, what is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existing Delphi code *translation*:

```
public static string ByteToHex(Byte InByte) {
  char[] Digits = new char[] {
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
  };  

  return string.Concat(Digits[InByte >> 4], Digits[InByte & 0x0F]);
}
```

Better implementation (all you want is *formatting*):

```
public static string ByteToHex(Byte InByte) => InByte.ToString("X2");
```

**Edit:** For **Delphi's** `Hi` and `Lo` (see comments) we have **C#**

```
// Second lowerest byte
public static byte Hi(int value) => (byte) ((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
// Lowerest byte
public static byte Lo(int value) => (byte) (value & 0xFF);
```

In general, the procedure is

1. *Shift* to the right (if required): e.g. `value >> 8` turns *second* last byte into *last* one
2. *Mask* with `0xFF`: we want one `byte` only: `& 0xFF`
3. *Cast* `int` to `byte`: `(byte)`

Comment: Thinks for your help yet again... What would the C# equivalent be of Hi(int) and Lo(int)?

Comment: Lo and Hi return the lowest and the second lowest bytes of integer (they are from 16-bit int era)

Comment: @Vamp_102: in *general case*, if you want to get `N`th last `byte` (`N = 0, 1, 2, 3...`) you can put `public static byte ByteFromEnd(int value) => (byte) ((value >> (8 * N)) & 0xFF);` please, see my edit for `Hi` and `Lo`